# DataAnnotations in EF 5 without code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm wondering if there is some new functionallity regarding data annotations in EF 5 or newer. I'm doing database-first so that as far as I know, I have to manipulate the T4 all the time which is quite a mess because with each EF-Version MS changes the default T4. So can someone tell me, if there is some alternative to things like that:

Manipulated T4:

```
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(inHeader: false, includeAnnotations: true)#>
[MetadataType(typeof(<#=code.Escape(entity)#>Metadata))]
<#=codeStringGenerator.EntityClassOpening(entity)#>
```

Resulting class sample if class is named 'Address':

```
[MetadataType(typeof(AddressMetadata))]
public partial class Address
{
```

Additional class for annotations in same namespace as generated 'Address'-class:

```
public class AddressMetadata
{

    [Display(Name = "Straße")]
    public string Street;

    [Display(Name = "Land")]
    public string Country;

    [Display(Name = "PLZ")]
    public string Zip;

    [Display(Name = "Stadt")]
    public string City;
}
```

Thats the way I do it today.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the generated code.  You can add the buddy class to a partial class.  Then, when the code is regenerated, you don't lose anything.

Comment: Yes, but then I have to react on database-updates manually. So if I use "Update database..." I have to go to the partial class and sync it to the generated one.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: OK, when I implement my class AddressMetadata in my sample code in the question everything works fine. Now imagine, I add a new column "HouseNumber" in the database table. Now when I update the EF Model my AddressMetadata-class will not recognize the change. Right? My question is, how I can automate these changes without editing T4.

Comment: @sprinter252 - I think you're a little confused about how things are supposed to work.  If you add a new column to your database, you have to update your buddy class anyways because Visual Studio can't magically figure out what validation you want on the items.  So you have to modify the buddy class if you modify the database.

Comment: I knwo that. Thats the reason I'm asking for another solution which obviously does not exist. It's kind of strange to have so much powerful things in EF and on  the other hand to have the need for editing T4 (automation) for such simple things like internationalization. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @sprinter252 - But you don't need to modify the T4.  That's the point of the buddy class.  The buddy class makes modifying the T4 pointless

Comment: No. Thats only true for properties which where there when the buddy class was modified the last time. When I add a db-field, the buddy class has to be modified to be informed about the new property by myself. To clear that out: I will create the buddy class inside my T4!

Comment: @sprinter252 - You just aren't making any sense.  I give up.

Comment: Do you see the 4th comment coming from you? Thats what I mean. If I update my T4 I don't have to do anything else after re-importing my database. I will post the solution here.